# Как в C# защитить свойства объекта, вызвавшего событие?

Tags: c#, .net, события

Всем доброго дня. Возник вопрос относительно событий в C#.

У нас есть Двигатель (Engine).

У Engine есть параметры модели ModelParams. Например, в параметры входит количество клапанов countOfClapans. В ModelParams определено событие paramsChanged, сигнализирующее об изменении параметров модели.

В процессе проектирования у меня возник вопрос: как защитить параметры модели от изменения через sender из обработчика события paramsChanged?
При этом я не хочу делать свойства параметров модели типа {get; private set{}}, чтобы запретить возможность редактирования свойств вне класса.

Насколько я понимаю, можно сделать отдельные события на изменение каждого параметра модели. Но что, если данных параметров много? Не делать же такое же количество обработчиков на события.

Одним словом, я стараюсь изолировать объект класса ModelParams от других объектов (в данном случае объектов класса Cylinder), которые будут подписываться на событие изменения модели.

Ниже приведен код в крайне упрощенном виде:

```
public class Engine {
    public ModelParams modelParams;
    public List<Cylinder> cylinders = new List<Cylinder>();


    public Engine( ModelParams modelParams ) {
        this.modelParams = modelParams;
    }
}

public class ModelParams {
    private int countOfClapans;
    private string engineType;

    public int ClapansCount {
        get { return countOfClapans; }
        set { countOfClapans = value; }
    }; 

    public int TypeOfEngine {
        get { return engineType; }
        set { engineType= value; }
    }; 


    public event EventArgs<ModelArgs> ModelChanged;

    public void OnModelChange() {
        if(modelChanged != null) {
            ModelArgs args = new ModelArgs();
            args.ClapansCount = this.ClapansCount;
            ModelChanged(this, args);
        }
    }
}

public class ModelArgs{
    private int countOfClapans;
    private string engineType;

    public int ClapansCount {
        get { return countOfClapans; }
        set { countOfClapans= value; }
    };

    public int TypeOfEngine {
        get { return engineType; }
        set { engineType= value; }
    }; 
}
```

Comment: никак, если у тебя есть ссылка на сам объект - ты всегда можешь изменить его свойства

Comment: сделать поля readonly или убрать сетер... - если не хотите его менять зачем вообще создавать?? а доступ к полю в класса остается

Comment: Параметры модели я планировал менять извне класса Engine.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду защитить? Защитить от artmoney? От изменений каких? От других классов? От других assembly?

Comment: Или может сделать что в set срабатывало один раз, т.е. если поставили 4 то на 2 уже не могли поменять?

Comment: Внутри Engine есть набор объектов класса Cylinder. Свойства класса Cylinder зависят от ModelParams. Я хотел запретить редактирование свойств ModelParams для объектов, входящих в класс Engine, при этом оставляя возможность редактирования ModelParams извне класса Engine. При этом предусматривая возможность не только замены объекта ModelParams целиком, но и редактирования каждого отдельного свойства без создания нового объекта ModelParams.

Comment: А разве не вы владелец класса Engine? Вы можете через reflection посмотреть стек вызовов, и если там есть класс Engine - не менять свойство. А поля - никак, поля должны быть private.

Comment: Я владелец класса. Просто хотел оградить от изменений ModelParams внутри этого класса. А все внешние изменения перехватывать через события внутри класса. Или этого делать не обязательно? А поля и должны были быть private. Это моя ошибка при наборе кода)

Comment: Являясь владельцем класса, вы можете ограничить, но на это вам понадобится несколько дней, не проще ли, как владельцу класса просто не менять это свойство?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильным методом мне кажется выдавать readonly-интерфейс наружу. Объявите интерфейс с геттерами и без сеттеров `IModelParams`, и используйте его в определении вашего `event`'а.

---

Если вы хотите ещё и защититься от тех, кто может злонамеренно сделать обратный каст к `ModelParams`, есть несколько путей.

Вы можете вынести `ModelParams` в отдельную сборку, отметить сеттеры как `internal`, и всех, кто должен иметь доступ к сеттерам, поместить в эту же сборку.

Или вы можете написать read-only-обёртку, которая будет содержать объект как приватное поле, и выдавать наружу только геттеры (а в геттерах брать значение из настоящего объекта).

---

Эти решения, в свою очередь, не сработают против рефлексии. Если кто-то злонамерненно пользуется рефлексией для того, чтобы получить доступ к приватным полям, ему нужно для начала настучать по мозгам через архитектора.

А если уж хочется защититься и от таких техническими, а не административными средствами, загрузите их код в отдельный `AppDomain` с урезанными правами, таким образом вы сможете не дать им воспользоваться рефлексией. Но я бы всё же рекомендовал путь доброго слова, документации и внушения со стороны архитектора: работать с кодом, которому не доверяешь — мучительное и неблагодарное занятие.

---

Обновление: Я перечитал ваш код, и понял, чего именно я недопонял:

Ваш `event`, судя по всему, определён как

```
public event EventHandler<ModelArgs> ModelChanged; // а не EventArgs<ModelArgs>
```

и что вы на самом деле передаёте в `event` `ModelParams` как `sender`, тип которого всё равно `object`? Если так, то это значит, что ваши клиенты таки делают downcast к типу `ModelParams`. Это значит, что просто создание интерфейса не поможет, и вам нужно пользоваться второй опцией: созданием обёрточного класса или вынесением типа `ModelParams` в отдельную сборку.

Comment: VladD, огромное спасибо за столь развернутый ответ!
Я правильно понял, что не надо переусердствовать с перестраховкой. То есть в таких случаях можно обойтись обычной оберткой в виде интерфейса, веря, что обработчик события не будет делать обратный каст?
Получается, что в объекте класса Engine в конструкторе надо сделать: Engine( IModelParams modelParams ). 

Если я правильно понял, то вопрос закрыт)

Comment: @Eladei: Да, я думаю, что просто экспортировать интерфейс должно быть достаточно. // Пожалуйста!

Comment: Последний вопрос, чтобы убедиться, что я Вас правильно понял). Вы говорили про импорт интерфейса? Ведь в предыдущем сообщении объект, поддерживающий интерфейс заносился в конструктор.

Comment: @Eladei: Под экспортом я имел в виду, что ваше событие _выставляет наружу_ тип-интерфейс, а не тип-объект.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Я остановился на следующем варианте, надеюсь, что он оптимален. Создается класс-обертка вокруг IModelDiesel. Доступ к данному объекту доступен только в режиме чтения. Модификация доступна внутри класса при помощи метода Update. Внутрь метода Update подается объект класса, реализующего IModelDiesel. Тем самым я могу вне обертки спокойно менять свойства объекта класса ModelDiesel, а затем подавать его в метод Update. Затем объект класса Cylinder подписывается на событие класса-обертки. Данное событие будет выставлять наружу тип-объект, а изменить IModelDiеsel не выйдет.

Comment: @Eladei: Да, выглядит хорошо.

Comment: Тогда вопрос закрыт). Еще раз большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

В C# в качестве события может выступать делегат с любой сигнатурой. EventHandler с его двумя параметрами это классический вариант, и его используют повсеместно. Но при большой необходимости можно объявить событие вот так:

```
public delegate void ModelChangeEventHandler(ModelArgs e);
public event ModelChangeEventHandler ModelChanged;
// или так
public event Action<ModelArgs>;
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет). Действительно, не надо жестко привязывать себя к одному единственному способу, как к догме).

Comment: Хороший вариант, кстати.